# How does domain users maintained in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, users, domain

How does domain users maintained in Ubuntu? Does it create Users locally (I think "NO")? As I don't see any entry for that user in /etc/passwd file.
Where it is stored. Who handles the domain user (like who creates profile locally, is it SSSD)?
Is there any way I can create user profile in same way?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is in itself a stand-alone client with or without server capabilities. If you would like to use it as an "Account Manager" server you need to install the necessary roles and they should be properly configured.

You can also join your stand-alone client to an existing "domain". This domain provider can be a Windows [Active-Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/virtual-dc/active-directory-domain-services-overview) or a RedHat [Identity Manager](https://access.redhat.com/products/identity-management) or a self managed LDAP.

In order to be able to help here to you I need to know to where did you join your Ubuntu.

1.) If you joined to an AD your domain accounts are in the database of the domain controller. You can reach it out that DB by using Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT).

2.) If you joined to a RedHat iDM your domain accounts are in the databes of the iDM server. You can reach it out by connecting to the web interface of iDB. This is coming with deployment of iDM (e.g. https://your-local-idm-server/)

3.) If you connect your local custom LDAP solution. Domain accounts are stored in your LDAP database.

*Final thoughts: your local accounts and your domain accounts are never identical. There are local and there are domain accounts for good reasons. If you are 100% sure that you connected your Ubuntu to a domain than try to access that server and try to access to the account database.*